# e1000e | intel onboard lan problems | ubuntu 18.04/19.10/20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

TL;DR:
My network interface seem to not accept/load/install the appropriate kernel driver module, e1000e. Only hint to a solution was from a dmesg hinting at that another driver (igb) is loaded.

Expected result:
 
Using onboard LAN, not using USB-tethering from phone.

Actual result:
Onboard lan won't load/bind the driver from the kernel module.

The affected hardware:
Gigabyte GA-Z87-UD3H - Onboard LAN - Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 05)

Have tried:
I have tried this on three boots: the original kubuntu 18.04 LTS. Most of the troubleshooting happened on this boot but I also tried some other ones on a separate SSD to see if it was release specific.

I've modprobed and compiled from source kernel modules for these kernels: 
4.15.0-96-lowlatency (came with 18.04 ubuntu-studio)
5.3.0-26/43/45/46-generic (original kubuntu 18.04, pop_os)
5.4.0-21/23-lowlatency (ubuntu-studio 20.04).

It used to work on the kubuntu 18.04 install for the last 6months-year. It has worked in the past on the same hardware under win 8.1, win 10, macos maverick/sierra/high sierra as well as ubuntu 16.04, 18.04.

Affected device:

```
sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for -: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 05
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7900000-f791ffff memory:f793d000-f793dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

sudo lspci -nnk gives me

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b] (rev 05)
        DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection I217-V [1458:e000]
        Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Notice the lack of the line "Kernel driver in use:" that I get on all devices/modules that do work.

```
modprobe e1000e 
modprobe -a e1000e
```

Doesnt do anything.

So I tried to compile from source:
(for the 5.4 module I followed steps from https://github.com/koljah-de/e1000e-dkms-debian to change a line in /usr/src/e1000e-3.6.0/src/kcompat.h:

```
line:command
2799:#include <linux/pci-aspm.h>
```

to

```
line:command
2799:#include <linux/pci.h>
```

which worked fine)

I tried to simply `make make install` and reboot the system, nothing. I tried the deb install method from the previously mentioned git. I tried

```
dkms add -m e1000e -v 3.6.0
dkms build -m e1000e -v 3.6.0
dkms  -m e1000e -v 3.6.0
```

Last ditch attempt to try to bind the interface manually:

`# apt install dpdk` and

```
sudo dpdk-devbind.py -b e1000e 0000:00:19.0
[sudo] password for -: 
Error: bind failed for 0000:00:19.0 - Cannot bind to driver e1000e
```

from journalctl I have these two relevant lines:

```
apr 10 19:55:43 a-Z87X-UD3H kernel: e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
apr 10 19:55:42 a-Z87X-UD3H kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
```

And from dmesg these ones:

```
[ 2173.754182] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.6.0-k
[ 2173.754183] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[ 5735.904821] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 5736.742509] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
[ 5736.742623] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 5737.579534] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

Judging from this dmesg the interface is loading the igb kernel module instead which has not showed up anywhere else, but this might be the cause of the problem. However, rmmod/modprobe -r hasnt managed to detach it as it's not technically loaded... I have also been unsuccessful in reproducing this dmesg. I'm stumped.

Comment: Please limit yourself to on-topic releases; Pop OS 19.10 is off-topic as it's neither Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu, Ubuntu *focal fossa* hasn't been released and is thus off-topic on this site (it becomes 20.04 only after it's release). In fact your whole question appears (as written) to be more of an off-topic rant https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because parts are off-topic, and parts are written as a rant in disguise - https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @guiverc Most of this has been under 18.04, the other two distros were to see if it was a distrospecific issue.

Comment: @guiverc askubuntu.com/help/on-topic has these two lines:  
"If a question involves any hardware issues, provide relevant information (Eg: If your question is about a graphics issue, provide video card type, video drivers and anything related to it)"
& "Questions should show as much information about your problem as possible. .."
Thus, the verbose description.If you have seen this problem before and know it is definitely not a Ubuntu specific issue, please point me in the right direction instead of dismissing it as "TL;DR".

Comment: As I read your post, you were on an on-topic release (18.04) which was then replaced by other off-topic non-Ubuntu then development Ubuntu so the on-topic system is gone; thus you're off-topic. The development release (20.04) is most useful to Ubuntu if you deal with your issue via bug reports or development channels as development releases provide the easiest chance to fix the problem for not just you, but also any other users with the same hardware - so please use bug tracking channels - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @guiverc the 18.04 boot is still there which I did try to dirty flash it with kubuntu 18.04 to reinstall / and maybe fix the problem. Pop was on a separate ssd and later replaced with ubuntu studio 20.04. The issue is still present both on the kubuntu 18.04 (supported) boot and the 20.04 (supported in 10 days) boot.

Comment: The pastes I see aren't for a 18.04 system, the 5.4 kernel is used by *focal fossa*, and  *focal fossa* is still a *development* release and things are constantly changing, eg. on Friday an upstream change with Qt (5.14.2/5.12.8) has caused a change and many rebuilds which are expected to complete Monday, these changes particularly impact Kubuntu/Lubuntu as they rely on Qt rather heavily. ie. until *focal fossa* is stable it's somewhat of a moving target (thus off-topic here)

Comment: @guiverc look, I've got two boots that I try every step on. The pastes here are from 18.04 except for the last one, which I couldn't reproduce on the first system. How about you make yourself useful and suggest something to try for troubleshooting on the 18.04 system rather than wasting everyone's time doubling down on this being off topic?

Comment: @guiverc as you can see, there are a plethora of kernels I've tried under 18.04 with no difference in outcome.